# How to populate zend_form from Doctrine2 entity?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Right now I'm populating/setDefaults a zend_form like this from the controller:

```
 $data = array('user' => $account->getUser(), 
            'password' => $account->getPassword(), 
            'name' => $account->getName());

 $form->setDefaults($data);
```

It's working but seams very manual the process. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It is somewhat manual, but it does provide at least some decoupling between field names in your form and member names in your entity. I usually push this down into a form method called something like `setDefaultsFromModel()` or just override `setDefaults()` to accept a model as well as an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that I apply was to add this function to the entity:

```
public function toArray ()
{
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

And then just:

```
$form->setDefaults($test->toArray());
```

Also if you need to do it the other way arround (array to object) you can take a look [here](https://github.com/cobbweb/Cob-ZendFramework-Doctrine2/blob/development/lib/Cob/Doctrine/ORM/EntityUtil.php)

Comment: This solution is not good if the Entity has Associations or properties that are not directly related to collumns.

Answer (score 4):

The "obvious" solution is to somehow factor out flattening entities into arrays.  This is not too hard to do, though some corner cases can get ugly.

The best-looking (I haven't tried it yet, but am about to) canned implementation I've run across is [this one](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary/blob/master/library/Bgy/Doctrine/EntitySerializer.php) (some [docs are here](http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary/#bgylib-components-bgy-doctrine-entity-serializer)).

It uses reflection to look at an entities metadata, and then makes some good guesses about what kind of structure to return.  This seems like the best strategy, overall.  I suspect that to handle unusually structured entities, you might want to tweak Boris' class to check for a custom serialization method on the entity, and if present, let the entity serialize itself.